# SPSS custom table percent and frequency in one cell

Tags: spss

By default, SPSS custom tables present percentage and frequency in distinct columns. How to merge them into a single cell? we want a format as follows:

N (%)

94 (38.4)

[Normal SPSS output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJP6S.png)

I have try the paste section of the spss custom table.